# How do I select a column whose name is a reserved word?

Tags: mysql

I have a column in MySQL database called "from".
But my query throws an error. 
What am I doing wrong?

```
SELECT name, to, from
FROM table1
```

> Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'from  FROM tables' at line 1

Comment: @lad2025,  I tried that, it gave me a column where everything was 'from'?

Comment: PROTIP: Instead of just saying "I get an error", you should **provide** the *exact* error message.

Comment: Best idea would be to avoid using that column name altogether... if you use the correct quotes ` as @lad2025 recommended, you should get the correct results. If you use regular ' then you will just get 'from' for all the rows.

Comment: Try: `SET sql_mode='ANSI_QUOTES';

SELECT "from", "to", "name"
FROM "table1"`

Comment: @lad2025 Thanks , i used the correct quotes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use backticks in order to select columns with reserved words as the column name:

```
SELECT `name`, `to` ,`from`
FROM table1
```

Comment: Hey, @Code-Monk, i get the words 'name', 'to' and 'from' in the columns instead of the values?

Comment: @AndroidAL that probably means you used single quotes instead of backticks. You need to use backticks here.

Comment: @McAdam331: I am already using the back ticks for the columns.

Comment: @Code-Monk I know you are, but what OP described means he didn't recognize your answer as backticks, but saw it as single quotes. That's why he got 'from' as the column values.

Answer (score 1):

From the [mysql documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/keywords.html):

> Reserved words are permitted as identifiers if you quote them as
>   described in Section 9.2, “Schema Object Names"

Table 9.2 provides the list of keywords and reserved words, which includes `FROM`.

Therefore:

```
select `from` from tablename
```

Also from that page:

> Exception: A word that follows a period in a qualified name must be an identifier, so it need not be quoted even if it is reserved

so this will work as well:

```
select tablename.from from tablename
```